# Graphics DrawString() clipping text off while rectangle still have more room

Tags: c#, graphics

I have something like this:

There are 3 rectangles of the same size width 60px each.

```
...
var font = new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold);
var format = new StringFormat() {FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.LineLimit} 
...
g.DrawString(content, font, brush, rect, format);
```

[image]

(Note: I put borders around text and a red line cutting before 'A's to make it easy to see the boundaries)

I realise the `DrawString()` is trimming off my **'M'** of 10 & 11 AM. However, if you examine how the red line cuts off the **'A's**, you see the first row of 'A' from 9:00 AM seats a couple pixels further away than the 2 A's below it, but AM didn't get trimmed off.

**That means, actually the rectangles DO still have enough space to fit the 'M' in, we can tell from the red line**, but `DrawString()` choose to clip it off instead, why? How to fix it?

Comment: Can you try increasing the width by a little amount such that the M's in the bottom rectangles can be seen..?

Comment: It is user drawing input from somewhere. I can't simply change from 60px to 62px for the user.

Comment: Unless rect (or content) is messed up this shouldn't happen. How do you set it?

Comment: Graphics.DrawString() is quite notorious for accuracy problems.  Just try "Hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii" as an example to see that you don't stand a chance.  You are going to need elbow grease.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope, setting format = `new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap, 1003) { Trimming = StringTrimming.None })`

```
RectangleF rec = new RectangleF();
rec.X = 100;
rec.Y= 100;
rec.Width = 100;
rec.Height = 20;
e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Black, new RectangleF[] { rec });
e.Graphics.DrawString("12345678901234", new Font("Arial", 9, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red, rec, 
new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap, 1003) { Trimming = StringTrimming.None });
```

Here's the output with `new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit, 1003)`
[image: Incorrect output]

and here's the correct output with `new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap, 1003) { Trimming = StringTrimming.None })`
[image]

will make a difference in your case.

Comment: Well, I have updated the answer part. you can check it out with your code also.

Comment: You saved my day! `Trimming = StringTrimming.None` works! Thank you. Point of interest is language code 1003. There is not much documentation on MSDN about what it is used for.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/453y15h2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Glad to help you. That language id is the international locale codes. Ie. 1033 for EN-US. 
Though you really don't need to use that number( if your application is locale based, otherwise doesn't matter.) Instead use, only Trimming and FormatFlags properties.
In case, you want to find locale codes for other languages, you can visit   [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx).